# Sideview Search Module Does Not Execute Search

Tags: splunk

I'm trying to use the dynamic HTML feature of Sideview to inject search results into my custom HTML. The problem is, any time I put a "Search" module into a dashboard the page hangs, and displays "Loading..." in the upper-right corner of the page. This happens even with an empty Search module. For instance, here is the page I'm trying to create.

XML:

```
 <module name="Search" layoutPanel="panel_row1_col1" autoRun="True">
    <param name="search"> | savedsearch last_command_by_engine</param>
    <module name="HTML">
      <param name="loadingText">Searching...</param>
      <param name="src">last_commands_table.html</param>
    </module>   
</module>
```

last_commands _table.html:

```
 <h1>Results: $results[0]$</h1>
    <h1>Search: $search$</h1>
    <table> 
            <thead>
                    <th>0</th>
                    <th>1</th>
                    <th>2</th>
                    <th>3</th>
                    <th>4</th>
                    <th>5</th>
                    <th>6</th>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
            </tbody>
    </table>
```

The HTML template is rendered but the search is not carried out. There's just the "Loading..." message at the top and nothing else happens.

Answer (score 0):

I would move this question to "[SplunkBase](http://splunk-base.splunk.com/)", if you are still having issues as that is the official Splunk forum. You can then tag the question with sideview related tags, and i'm sure the user "@sideview" would pick it up quite quickly.. He is usually very active on the forum and very helpful.

Not a direct answer, but hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You may already have the answer but it is simply to move the HTML module out of the search module. Nesting like that won't work.